# Software automatic content analysis of pdf files

Tags: metadata, search-engines, analysis

Is there an open sourc/ commercial software which can perform automatic content analysis (to produce wishful summaries) in a large collection of pdf documents which have tagged meta-data for easy classification? What is the technology Google uses to parse web-hosted pdf and rank them?

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure what Google uses, but it's possible to read and create PDF documents server-side with a software component such as ABCpdf.NET.  This requires some knowledge of programming in ASP or ASP.NET (Active Server Pages) for Microsoft IIS servers, or PHP for Apache web servers.

Comment: I'm looking for something which does the intelligent text mining in a vast database of pdf files..it can be a desktop app/scripts etc..Google can parse lots of different fileformats and search for textual content